# Cursor related \b, \r in C language

Tags: c

I'm using visual studio community 2019, and use C language in Window 10.

I understood a use of \b and \r.

They move cursor without delete any text.

But when \b or \r is used at the last of program, it delete one letter.

ex)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
printf("abcd\r");
}
```

It prints [ bcd]

I can't understand why this phenomenon happen.

Comment: The space is being printed by something after this. It overwrites the `a`.

Comment: E.g. when the program ends, your shell prompt is printed. It will overwrite what you printed.

Comment: Windows 7 command line, cannot reproduce. Is there actually a space after the `\r`?

Comment: This is why you should always end output of a program with `\n`, so that the prompt starts on a new line instead of being mixed in with the program's output.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Your answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting, i never seen that before now to be honest: But i have come across this while trying to learn how to output text to a static control with a simple Win32 App. I put this as a sample for my own reference but maybe it would help you?

White space issues seem to become more and more important especially if you delve into CMAKE files (Something to do with the compiler files that make your programs).

Variable name declared as a type LPCWSTR, Not a complete minimal program if you need i can share.. ??
LPCWSTR StaticName_Extra(LPCWSTR)
{

```
const wchar_t* Anicdotes = L"Basically using this format\n\
I can write anything i want as long as i want (?)\n\
and just keep going respectively.\n\
A New Line requires 2 new line marks... \n\
While more is good \n\
using the 'backslash n backslash' to end any line it is also very important to \n\
make sure the code denotes this with a 'backslash n backslash' directly \n\
after the last line of text via wchar_t* variable content\n\
white space is imperative to take into account lol \n\
So how do i add this as a wchar_t statement in this text format! well - \\n\\ \n\
\r\
\r\
\\r\\ then there is carriage return done \n\
\r\
\r\
\t\ \t\ \t\ \t\ \t\ \t\ \\t\\Tab marker! \n\
\n\
 ";

return (LPCWSTR)Anicdotes;
```

}

It was fun to play around with the different ways i can output text when i am restricted.